# jQuery not receiving values of input elements

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a list of users, and each one has a small form underneath where an admin can add his own comments. like so:

```
<form name="update_comment_99" method="post" action="">
    <td colspan="4">
        <input type="text" name="sortering" id="sortering" placeholder="job" value="">
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="99" name="uid" id="uid">
        <a name="comment_button" id="comment_button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right  comment-button">Update 
            <li class="icon-circle-arrow-up icon-white"></i>
        </a>
</form>
    </td>
```

Then I have an event handler that works with the button:

```
$('#cvDatabase').on('click', '.comment-button', function() {
    var uid = $('input[name=uid]');
    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
    var sortering = $('input[name=sortering]');
    var dataString = 'uid='+uid.val()+'&comment='+comment.val()+'&sortering='+sortering.val();
    alert(dataString);
```

The problem that I have is that jQuery doesn´t get the user input of the form elements, only when the are pre-populated with "value=".

I have done this countless of times without problem, but for some reason this is not working at all!

Comment: if you give an ID its unique, so you could use it for jQuery instead of the long travesal lookup with name=.

Comment: What's the output?  Is there anything in your error console?

Comment: What is `#cvDatabase` I dont find anything with that ID

Comment: why are you using $('#cvDatabase').on('click', '.comment-button' ...) and not $('.comment-button').on('click' ...)?

Comment: `.comment-button` instead of `.comment_button`

Comment: Why do you use deffered event handling? Does your form dynamically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var uid = $tr.find('input[name=uid]');
var comment = $tr.find('textarea[name=comment]');
var sortering = $tr.find('input[name=sortering]');

var dataString = 'uid=' + uid.val() + '&comment=' + comment.val() + '&sortering=' + sortering.val();
alert(dataString);
```

Using `$('input[name=uid]')` gives you the object of the first input not the element near to the `comment` button you have currently clicked.

Comment: Bingo! :) Obvious solution that missed my attention. Thank you Palash!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lwh4C/1/

```
 $(document).on('click', '.comment-button',function(){
            var uid = $('input[name=uid]');
            var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
            var sortering = $('input[name=sortering]');
            var dataString = 'uid='+uid.val()+'&comment='+comment.val()+'&sortering='+sortering.val();
            alert(dataString);
    });
```

Comment: use $(document).on('click', '.comment-button') instead - live is deprecated

Comment: Use `on` instead of `live`, as `live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see

http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/5/

```
$('#comment_button').on('click', function() {
        var uid = $('input[type=hidden]').attr('id');
        var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]').val();
        var sortering = $('input[name=sortering]').val();
        var dataString='uid='+uid+'&comment='+comment+'&sortering='+sortering
        alert(dataString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.comment-button').live('click',function() {
        var uid = $('#uid');
        var comment = $('#comment');
        var sortering = $('#sortering');
        var dataString = 'uid='+uid.val()+' &comment='+comment.val()+' &sortering='+sortering.val();
        alert(dataString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/tdmYM/1/)

```
 $("#comment_button").click(function() {
   var uid = $("#uid").val()
    var comment = $("#comment").val()
    var sortering = $("#sortering").val()
    var dataString = 'uid='+uid+'&sortering='+sortering+'&comment='+comment;
    alert(dataString);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

lets do it the general way, dont worry about new added input elements if needed, it will generate your `dataString` with still very very powerfull javascript + jQuery.

```
<form name="update_comment_99" method="post" action="">
    <td colspan="4">
        <input type="text" name="sortering" id="sortering" placeholder="Type of job" value="" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="99" name="uid" id="uid"/>
        <a id="comment_button" href="#">Update <i class="icon-circle-arrow-up icon-white"></i></a>
    </td>
</form>
<script>
$("#comment_button").on('click', function(){
    var dataString=$('form[name=update_comment_99]').find('input,textarea').map(
        function(){return this.name+"="+this.value;}
    ).splice(0).join('&');
    alert(dataString);
    //for multiple selects this may not work so simple, but thats not your question
});
</script>
```

Fork to fiddle around with http://jsfiddle.net/36aS9/